# Solidity compiler 0.8.5 "Unreachable code." Warning on certain parts of code that worked before

Tags: solidity, compiler

Now that I'm using the 0.8.5 compiler, I'm getting a warning that says "Unreachable code." for parts of my functions that didn't have any issues until 0.8.5 (works on any below that). Does anyone know why this is happening or if it's a bug?

I'm using OpenZeppelin's ERC721 contract.

```
function sellNFT(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _sellPrice) public {
   require(
      _sellPrice > 2e12,
      "Sale Error: Sell price must be greater than 2e12 (2 szabos)."
   );
   safeTransferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);

   // Compiler warning: "Unreachable code."
   emit TokenTransferredToExchange(msg.sender, _tokenId, _sellPrice); // <- Warning here

   _tokenInfo[_tokenId] = TokenSeller(
      _tokenId,
      msg.sender,
      _sellPrice,
      getTokenValue(_tokenId)
   );
}
```

```
function buyToken(uint256 _tokenId) public payable {
        TokenSeller memory tokenData = getTokenSellData(_tokenId);
        address tokenOwner = tokenData.tokenOwner;
        uint256 tokenSalePrice = tokenData.tokenSalePrice;
        require(
            msg.value == tokenSalePrice,
            "Purchase Error: Purchase amount doesn't equal the sell price."
        );
        payContract();

        this.safeTransferFrom(address(this), msg.sender, _tokenId);
        emit TokenPurchased(_tokenId, msg.sender, address(tokenOwner));

        
        _paySellerAfterPurchase(tokenOwner, tokenSalePrice);

        // Same working here, "Unreachable code.":
        delete _tokenInfo[_tokenId];
    }
```

ANSWER: This is a known issue and there will be a bug fix soon.

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11522

Comment: It is a bug in solc 0.8.5 https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11522.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and there will be a bug fix soon.

https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11522